# wordpress with non-wordpress subfolder: google search console shows 403 error for file in subfolder although page is accessible

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, google-search-console

I have a wordpress page with wordpress installed in the main directory. The non-wordpress subfolders (uebungen) are subfolders of the main directory:

maindirectory

- wp-content
- wp-admin
- wp-includes
- uebungen

Files in the subdirectory are accessible for human users, for example:
https://mathetoolbar.de/uebungen/koerper-benennen.html

The subfolder https://mathetoolbar.de/uebungen/ itself is not accessible for human users and throws a 403 error. This is the desired behaviour.

Google search console also opens the individual files (complete link) in the subfolder correctly, however when I let google test the url above, it reports a 403 error and says the page can't be listed.

Other files in the same subdirectory (uebungen) are listed in Google and seem to work. However I don't see the difference and I'm concerned, that something might have changed and Google will delist them all in time.

I checked google developer tools. The 403 error is not visible there. I regenerated the .htaccess file. It is Wordpress standard now:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# End WordPress
```

I checked similar questions in the Internet, but they all seem to concern either access to the subfolder itself not access to the complete file-link or the file-link is not accessible at all (not for humans either).

I deactivated the security plugin I'm using for a short time and tested the url's in Google again, but it didn't help.

Comment: “Halte das Handy waagerecht, um die Anwendung zu sehen.”

Comment: There is no obvious, easily apparent reason why Google should get a 403 here. You mentioned some "security plugin", what exactly does that do? (And even if you deactivated it, perhaps the "results" of its actions are still cached somewhere, somehow.)

Comment: The problem apparently disappeared. I uninstalled a plugin "Security Shield". It didn't solve the problem instantly so I'm not sure this is the reason.